# I am trying to add background image through inline css in JSX react but it doesn't gets updated

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const customStyle = {
  color : "red"

}

const dStyle = {
  backgroundImage : "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2771916.jpg", // unable to view this image as background-image
}

ReactDOM.render(
<div style = {dStyle}>
  <h1 style = {customStyle}>Hello World!
  </h1>
  </div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

i have tried to do the above by eternal styling it and it happened but through inline css i am unable to get the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in inline css just add `url(...)` as below

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const customStyle = {
  color : "red"

}

const dStyle = {
  backgroundImage : "url(https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2771916.jpg)",
}

ReactDOM.render(
<div style = {dStyle}>
  <h1 style = {customStyle}>Hello World!
  </h1>
  </div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: it works , here is link of sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-glitter-f6x6u @DeepakKumar

Comment: oh!! Now it's working. i dunno why it didn't work earlier. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(require("https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2771916.jpg"))` }}>
```

**Solution 2:**

```
import React from "react";
import Background from 'https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2771916.jpg';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const customStyle = {
  color : "red"

}

const dStyle = {
  backgroundImage: "url(" + { Background } + ")" // unable to view this image as background-image
}

ReactDOM.render(
<div style = {dStyle}>
  <h1 style = {customStyle}>Hello World!
  </h1>
  </div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: the code is still not working. i even copied the same code but still, it loads error

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

First store your imageUrl in a variable and then use **style** prop as follows:

```
const TestingImage = () => {
  const imageUrl = "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2771916.jpg";
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
          height: "400px",
        }}
      ></div>
    </>
  );
};
```